# Not showing Selected Value in Lambda Expression in View Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller with a action

```
public ActionResult ActionName(int ID)
{
   ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(Student, "StudentID", "StudentName", ID);
   return View()
}
```

In the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentID, ViewBag.StudentID as SelectList, "Select Student", new{ @class = ".."})
```

This field is a required field, the razor is not rendering with the selected value and the require field is working 
But when i use

```
@Html.DropDownList("StudentID", null, "Select Student", new{ @class = ".."})
```

The razor renders the selected Value, that require is not working in the above code

Comment: You cannot use the same name for the model property and `ViewBag` property. Change it to (say)  `ViewBag.StudentList = new SelectList(Student, "StudentID", "StudentName")` (the last parameter is not required because its the value of the model property that determines what is selected

Comment: i want to show the selected value along the require validation

Comment: And using the code in my comment will do that (with `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentID, ViewBag.StudentList as SelectList, "Select Student", ...)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StudentID)`

Comment: Yes, it worked man. So we should not give the model property name in the ViewBag right

Comment: Yes, they need to be different. No time now but I'll add an answer later explaining whats happening behind the scenes and why you don't get client side validation if they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the same name for the model property and ViewBag property. Change it to (say)

```
ViewBag.StudentList = new SelectList(Student, "StudentID", "StudentName")
```

Note that the 4th parameter in your example is not required because its the value of the model property that determines what is selected.

and in the view use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentID, ViewBag.SelectList as SelectList, "Select Student", new{ @class = ".."})
```

In the case of your first method (`@Html.DropDownListFor()`) the option is not selected because internally the method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in order to set the `Selected` property before building the html. While building this, it looks for a value in the `ViewDataDictionary` for a key with the name `StudentID` and finds one which is `System.Web.Mcv.SelectList` but there are no options with a value `"System.Web.Mcv.SelectList"` so none of the options are generated with `Selected = true`.

In the case of the second method(`@Html.DropDownList()`) you provide `null` as the second parameter, so internally the helper uses your `ViewBag` property to generate the options, but now your not binding to a model property so the helper does not generate any `data-val-*` attributes.